# Создать необходимый массив в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Дано:

```js
const [tablesChecked, setTablesChecked] = useState(true); // 'Tables'
const [objectsChecked, setObjectsChecked] = useState(true); // 'Objects'
const [contextChecked, setContextChecked] = useState(true); // 'Contexts'
const [linksChecked, setLinksChecked] = useState(true); // 'Links'
```

Создать массив, который будет содержать в себе строки, которые соответствуют переменным `tablesChecked`, `objectsChecked`, `contextChecked`, `linksChecked`.
Например, если переменная `tablesChecked` и `objectsCheked` равны `true`, то результирующий массив должен быть вида `['Tables', 'Objects']`.
Подсказка: значения переменных меняются в помощью чек-боксов. Пример

```js
<CheckBox onClick={(event) => setTablesCheked(event.target.checked)}
```

Comment: Оказывается мы на собесе, сколько будете платить?

Comment: @DaYa не понятно ваше возмущение. Пропустите, если нечего сказать по существу

Comment: ну, я возможно не в правилах комьюнити пишу, поправьте тогда. собес не мой, он прошел, на вопрос не ответили. все в прошлом, так сказать. просто хотелось бы понять ответ.

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо, поправил

Comment: @antoniouo Чекбоксы менять можно и функцию клика?

Comment: @SwaD да, можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один вариантов реализации. Каждому чек боксу задаем id по соответствующим переменным
Реализуем функцию, в которую будет приходит событие нажатие мыши и функция set*() для установки значений в state.
В зависимости от значения checked либо добавляем данные в массив, либо удаляем.

```
export default function App() {
  const [tablesChecked, setTablesChecked] = useState(false); // 'Tables'
  const [objectsChecked, setObjectsChecked] = useState(false); // 'Objects'
  const [contextChecked, setContextChecked] = useState(false); // 'Contexts'
  const [linksChecked, setLinksChecked] = useState(false); // 'Links'
  const [mas, setMas] = useState([""]);

  const save = (e, fnc) => {
    if (e.checked) {
      const oldMas = mas;
      oldMas.push(e.id);
      setMas([...oldMas]);
    } else {
      setMas(mas.filter((item) => item !== e.id));
    }
    fnc(e.checked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="Tables"
        checked={tablesChecked}
        onClick={(event) => save(event.target, setTablesChecked)}
      />
      <br/>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="Objects"
        checked={objectsChecked}
        onClick={(event) => save(event.target, setObjectsChecked)}
      />
      <br/>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="Contexts"
        checked={contextChecked}
        onClick={(event) => save(event.target, setContextChecked)}
      />
      <br/>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="Links"
        checked={linksChecked}
        onClick={(event) => save(event.target, setLinksChecked)}
      />
      <br/>
      {mas.map((it) => (
        <span>{it}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Потестировать можно здесть https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dubinsky-196xfj?file=/src/App.js