# Как создать динамический список из input, что бы вводимые значения не дублировались и вели себя как отдельные элементы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Задача - вывести некоторые данные по **get** запросу c нескольких произвольных **url**.

Для этого я хочу создать динамический список из input элементов. 
Я реализовал кнопки добавления новых input и удаления предыдущих

После добавления новых инпутов и последующем вводе данных в любой из них, во всех остальных введенные данные также сразу появляются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const initialUrl = [
    {
        url: ''
    }
]

const newUrl= {
    url: ''
}

const initialData = [
    {
        data: ''
    }
]

const newData = {
    data: ''
}

function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')  
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl)
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialData)
    const [result, setResult] = useState()

function handleChange(event) {
        setValue(event.target.value)
}
  
function addField () {
    setUrl(url.length < 10 ? [...url, newUrl] : url)
    setData([...data, newData])
}

function removeField () {
    setUrl(url.length > 1 ? url.filter((note, index) => index !== url.length - 1) : url)
    setData(data.filter((note, index) => index !== url.length - 1))
} 

async function handleClick() {
    if (validator.isURL(value)) {
        await axios.get(value)          
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {                  
                    setResult(response.headers)
            }})
            .catch(function (error) {
                if (error.response) {               
                    setResult(error.response.status)
            }})
    } else {
        setErrorMessage(' Некорректный URL')
    }
}

return <div>

    <div>

        <h1>URLs</h1>

            <div>
                {url.map((item, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} /> 
                        {errorMessage}
                    </div>
                    ))}
            </div>

            <div>
                <button onClick={removeField}>
                    Remove field
                </button>
            </div>

            <div>                           
                <button onClick={addField}>
                    Add Field
                </button>               
            </div>

            <div>
                <button onClick={handleClick}>
                    Get data
                </button>
            </div>              
    </div>

    <h1>Answers</h1>

    <div>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                Результат запроса: {result}
            </div>
            ))}
    </div>

</div>;
}
```

Как реализовать **динамический список в React.JS**, что бы каждый новый input вел себя как **отдельный элемент**?

Comment: Вопрос в титульной части задан довольно просто... А описание для чего такое?
У тебя не получается проверить массив на повторяющиеся значения?

Comment: @ksa не могу понять логику отработки кода и возникающей ошибки в контексте реакта.

Comment: У вас 1 переменная **value** на все инпуты. Вынесете инпут в отедельный компонент со своим стейтом или value преобразуйте, допустим, в массив значений. Что то подобное даже вам [показывал как сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1459137) - там правда значения статические

Comment: @SwaD спасибо, подход примерно стал понимать, но логику так и не могу продумать в динамике и нескольких инпутах(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания динамического списка, необходимо для каждого нового элемента этого списка организовать свое хранилище данных.

В большинстве случаев, для этого идеально подходит массив.

Создадим шаблон для новых элементов. Делаем это так, что бы в каждом элементе были все необходимые значения.

```
const newUrl = {
  id: 0,
  url: "",
  errorMessage: "",
  result: "",
  data: ""
};
```

Наш список будет представлен массивом объектов **newUrl**.
Массив будем хранить в переменной состояния **value**

- Для создания нового **input** будем пушить(добавлять) новый элемент в **value**. Функция `addField()`

  ```js
  function addField() {
      if (value.length < 10) {
        const added = [...value]; // Получаем текущее состояние
        const data = { ...newUrl }; // Получаем шаблон элемента
        data.id = lastId + 1; // Записываем новый ID
        added.push(data); // Добавляем элемент
        setId((e) => ++e); // Увеличиваем ID
        setValue(added); // Обновляем состояние
      }
    }
  ```
- При удалении - удалять элемент методом **filter()**. Функция `removeField(index)` - в качестве параметра передаем индекс массива для исключения.

  ```js
  function removeField(index) {
      // Фильтруем массив по индексу элемента
      setValue(value.filter((item, idx) => index !== idx));
  }
  ```
- При получении данных и изменения значений в input будем менять элемент массива. Функция `handleChange(event, index)` будет отвечать за изменение данных внутри input, а функция `handleClick(index, url)` будет отвечать за получение данных от внешнего API и сохранения состояния.

  ```js
  function handleChange(event, index) {
      const valueNew = [...value]; // Получаем текущее состояние
      valueNew[index].url = event; // Меняем значение
      setValue(valueNew); // Сохраняем состояние
  }
  ```

  ```js
    async function handleClick(index, url) {
      if (validator.isURL(url)) {
        await axios
          .get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              const resNew = [...value]; // Получаем текущее состояние
              resNew[index].result = response.headers; // Меняем значение
              setValue(resNew); // Сохраняем состояние
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response) {
              const resNew = [...value];
              resNew[index].result = error.response.status;
            }
          });
      } else {
        const resNew = [...value];
        resNew[index].errorMessage = "Некорректный URL";
        setValue(resNew);
      }
    }
  ```

Теперь соберем все это вместе и получим необходимый нам компонент с реализованным динамическим списком input'ов

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([{ ...newUrl }]);
  const [lastId, setId] = useState(0);

  function handleChange(event, index) {
    const valueNew = [...value];
    valueNew[index].url = event;
    setValue(valueNew);
  }

  function addField() {
    if (value.length < 10) {
      const added = [...value];
      const data = { ...newUrl };
      data.id = lastId + 1;
      added.push(data);
      setId((e) => ++e);
      setValue(added);
    }
  }

  function removeField(index) {
    setValue(value.filter((item, idx) => index !== idx));
  }

  async function handleClick(index, url) {
    if (validator.isURL(url)) {
      await axios
        .get(url)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            const resNew = [...value];
            resNew[index].result = response.headers;
            setValue(resNew);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          if (error.response) {
            const resNew = [...value];
            resNew[index].result = error.response.status;
          }
        });
    } else {
      const resNew = [...value];
      resNew[index].errorMessage = "Некорректный URL";
      setValue(resNew);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>URLs</h1>

        <div style={{ width: 500 }}>
          {value.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} style={{ width: 500 }}>
              {item.id + " "}
              <input
                value={item.url}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, index)}
              />{" "}
              <button onClick={() => handleClick(index, item.url)}>
                Get data
              </button>{" "}
              <button onClick={() => removeField(index)}>Remove field</button>
              {item.errorMessage}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />

        <div>
          <button onClick={addField}>Add Field</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h1>Answers</h1>

      <div>
        {value.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            Результат запроса {item.id}: {item.result}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Если данные элементов не нужно собирать в одном компоненте, то input'ы можно вынести в отдельные компоненты с созданием собственного состояния, это предотвратит перерисовку родительского компонента и всех дочерних. Пример того, [как вынести элемент списка в отдельный компонент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474996/1475029#1475029)

[Зачем используется spread оператор для обновления состояния компонента в React?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467523/1468251#1468251)

Comment: Тестировал [в песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/dunamic-inputs-tuv45f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: большое спасибо! а как правильно навесить кнопку единого запроса на все инпуты (вместо или вместе с запросами на каждый отдельно)?

Comment: Единый запрос на все инпуты должен поддерживать ваш API. Либо долбить в цикле всех по очереди, либо отправлять все запросы одной пачкой(должен поддерживать ваш бэк)

Comment: а можно ли обойти политику CORS и выводить headers буквально с любого адреса? либо вывести соответствующее сообщение в ответ

Comment: Можете детализировать, о чем речь?

Comment: при запросе, к примеру, на habr.com, возникает следующее сообщение Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://habr.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Я точно не знаю, не сталкивался. Покопайтесь в [вопросах-ответах-комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=CORS), наверняка найдете ответ. Вопросов по CORS много задается.