# Есть несколько инпутов range, для них одно состояние, как изменять каждый отдельно?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть несколько инпутов range, для них одно состояние, как изменять value каждого отдельно?
Когда я перетаскиваю один из них, то изменяются все. Приложение работает логично, и это поведение понятно.
Но как можно сделать, чтобы отдельно изменять каждый? .

Я перебирал с map информацию которая мне приходит с запроса, и как это реализовать никак не получается.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const DonateList = () => {
    const [donateList, setDonateList] = useState([]);
    const [rangePrice, setRangePrice] = useState(0);

    const rangeChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setRangePrice(parseInt(e.target.value));
    }
    return (
        <>
            {donateList.map((post: any, index: number) => (
                <div className="donate__item" key={index}>
                    <img src="http://localhost:3000/static/media/02.d091f12c6b2a8040aabb.webp" alt="" className="donate-item__img" />
                    <div className="donate-item__content">
                        <div className="donate-item__title">{post.title}</div>
                        <div className="donate-item__description">{post.description}</div>
                        <div className="donate-item__range-content">
                            <input type="range" min={0} max={post.price} className='donate-item__range' onChange={rangeChange} value={rangePrice} />
                            <span className="donate-item__price">{rangePrice}/{post.price}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default DonateList;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Возможно это ответ на ваш вопрос [Декомпозиция элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478184/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-input-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb/1478652#1478652)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ был SwaD'а.

Vasily, если будет возможность, то напишите пожалуйста пример кода, как оно должно выглядеть

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает пока репутации писать комментарии, поэтому напишу в ответе. :)

Если для всех нужно иметь один стейт, значит единственный выход - хранить в стейте массив объектов типа {key: xxx, value: yyy}. key брать тот который присваиваешь в map (у тебя это index).

При обновлении стейта не забудь обновлять через создание! нового объекта, а не изменение свойства объекта, т.е. нужно обновлять, используя спрэд-оператор.

Comment: Не единственный! Можно input вынести в отдельный компонент со своим стейтом

Comment: Vasily, если будет возможность, то напишите пожалуйста пример кода, как оно должно выглядеть

Answer (score 1):

Апдейт по просьбе @brutal
Brutal, код не идеальный. Можно короче. Но код работает и демонстрирует идею.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

interface IInput {
  key: string,
  label: string,
  value: string
}

const inputs: IInput[] = [
  {
    key: '1',
    label: 'label 1',
    value: ''
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    label: 'label 2',
    value: ''
  }
]

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IInput[]>(inputs);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state from useEffect', state)
  }, [state])

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputIndex = Number(e.target.id);
    const modifiedInput = {
      ...state[inputIndex],
      value: e.target.value
    }
    const stateArray = [...state];
    stateArray.splice(inputIndex, 1, modifiedInput);
    setState([...stateArray]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ 'display': 'flex', 'flexDirection': 'column', 'width': '250px' }}>
        {
          inputs.map((input, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index} style={{ 'display': 'flex' }}>
                <label htmlFor={`${input.key}`}>{input.label}</label>
                <input
                  id={index as unknown as string}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={state[index]?.value}
                />
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
      <div style={{ 'display': 'flex', 'flexDirection': 'column' }}>
        <h2>State values</h2>
        <span>{`0: ${state[0]?.value}`}</span>
        <span>{`1: ${state[1]?.value}`}</span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```