# Проблема с удалением компонента из массива React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня есть массив компонентов в App. В массиве хранятся компоненты Category, в category я попытался написать функцию удаления выбранного элемента из массива, но я не понимаю как передать в функцию индекс элемента, который был выбран. Так же если удалять элементы из массива с помощью React Dev Tools у элементов после удаленного очищаются стейты, а из-за этого у элементов пропадают названия.

**App:**

```
import React, { useState, ReactElement } from "react";
import Category from "./components/Category";
import "./css/style.css";
import CategoryList from "./components/Category";

function App() {
  const [categoryArray, setCategoryArray] = useState<ReactElement[]>([]);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const newIndex = categoryArray.length;
    setCategoryArray((prevArray: ReactElement[]) => [
      ...prevArray,
      <Category
        key={prevArray.length}
        categoryArray={categoryArray}
        setCategoryArray={setCategoryArray}
      />,
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="categories">
        <div className="categories-block">
          <p>Categories</p>
        </div>
        <p className="plus" onClick={handleAdd}>
          +
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="subcategories">
        {categoryArray.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Category:**

```
import React, { useState, ReactElement } from "react";
import "../css/category.css";

function Category({
  categoryArray,
  setCategoryArray,
}: {
  categoryArray: ReactElement[];
  setCategoryArray: Function;
}) {
  const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState<string>("");
  const [currentName, setCurrentName] = useState<string>("");
   
  const handleDelete = (indexToDelete: number) => {
    setCategoryArray((prevArray: ReactElement[]) =>
      prevArray.filter((_, index) => index !== indexToDelete)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="Category">
      <div className="category">
        <div className="category-block">
          <div className="category-text">
            <p className={isCategoryVisible ? "name-active" : "name"}>
              {currentName}
            </p>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => setCategoryName(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Category name"
              className={inputActive ? "" : "input-disable"}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={inputActive ? "edit-menu" : "edit-menu-active"}>
          <p className="plus edit-menu-item">+</p>
          <p className="edit edit-menu-item" onClick={handleEdit}>
            E
          </p>
          <p className="delete edit-menu-item" onClick={() => handleDelete}>
            X
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Category;
```

Comment: Исправьте опечатки в заголовке.

Comment: У вас что то непонятное написано... Если categoryArray это у вас список элементов, то зачем вы каждому новому элементу в пропсы запихиваете этот список вмесие с функцией сохранения(а потом не используете)? Так же вы рендерите компонент Category и передаете item(как чилдрен), но в самом компоненте это не используете и не выводите. Т.к. в самом компоненте Category вы не оперируете данными, полученными из родительского массива, то узнать, где какое событие происходит, мягко говоря, сложно.

Comment: @SwaD половину кода я убрал, т.к. он не относится к функции удаления. Массив я добавляю, чтобы изменить его с помощью функции удаления в компоненте.

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478184/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-input-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb/1478652#1478652) Там ниже есть ссылка не песочницу, где как раз реализовано управление списком элементов с удалением